# Aplicacion rails con base de datos remota

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy iniciando en **ruby on rails** y quiero hacer una aplicación conectada a **mysql**, pero la base de datos esta en un servidor remoto.
Tengo que crear la base datos con anterioridad o lo hago después desde la consola con rake db:create?

***Así tengo mi database.yml:***

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  host: 192.168.1.xx
```

y este es el error que obtengo:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'app_name_development'

¿ Alguien tiene alguna idea de como realizar esta tarea ?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas unicamente tener disponible la conexión con el servidor remoto y configurar esta conexión en el database.yml.

> Nota: La base de datos en tu servidor, debe estar configurada para
>   aceptar conexiones remotas.

```
  production: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf-8
  pool: 5
  username: "username"
  password: "password"
  host: "hostname"
  port: "port number"
  database: "database name"
```

Lo demas sigue siendo igual, creación, migraciones y carga de datos puedes seguir realizándolos de la manera estándar.

Para configurar Mysql y aceptar conexiones remotas en el archivo

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

comenta la linea

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: gracias, pero no tenga esa linea en el archivo my.cnf

Comment: Puede cambiar segun el sistema operativo e instalación de mysql